# How to add a new version of VASP in pyiron

Tags: pyiron

I have a new and compiled version of VASP that performs magnetic constrains of the local moment orientations on-the-fly, which I'd like to test and use with pyiron.

Please could you provide guidance and steps to follow in order to add this version of VASP to pyiron as one more executable?

Thank you,
Eduardo

Answer (score 0):

You need to add corresponding run script(s) to the pyiron resources.

In your `.pyiron` config file the paths for the resources are stated as `RESOURCE_PATHS = /comma/separated/list, /of/paths/to/the/resources`.

In the resources you need to add the run scripts in the directory `vasp/bin/` using the naming convention `run_code_version[_mpie].sh`. The actual run script is, of course, dependent on the cluster and the libraries used to build VASP and might look similar to

- `run_vasp_version.sh` (single core version):

```
module load intel/...
srun -n 1 /path/to/the/new/executable/version/vasp_std
```

- `run_vasp_version_mpie.sh` (mpi version):

```
module load intel/... impi/...
srun -n $1 /path/to/the/new/executable/version/vasp_std
```

Please have a look at the other vasp run scripts which you have used from the shared resources.

(For MPIE colleagues: Detailed examples for the setup/run scripts for vasp on cmti can be found [in this privat repo](https://github.com/eisenforschung/pyiron-resources-mpie/tree/master/vasp/bin).)